# Retirar várias porcentagens proporcionais a um único valor

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal! Estou enfrentando pequeno probleminha aqui com cálculo de porcentagem e estou tendo dificuldade para chegar no objetivo final.

Eu tenho que calcular a diferença percentual de cada recebedor na compra, de acordo com o total da compra. Sendo que no final a soma total da porcentagem de cada recebedor tem que bater 100%.

**Vamos tentar calcular:**

Primeiramente eu tenho esses recebedores, cada um já tem o seu amount (estão em centavos):

```
$recipients = [
      [
        "recipient_id" => "re_cisc9ja1e01u1gd6elgn8iudx",
        "charge_processing_fee" => false,
        "liable" => false,
        "amount" => 3000.0
      ],
      [
        "recipient_id" => "re_cisc9jb9c01we2m6dueafa586",
        "charge_processing_fee" => true,
        "liable" => false,
        "amount" => 1000.0,
      ],
      [
        "recipient_id" => "re_cisc9jbvz01wf2m6dogbkj6z1",
        "charge_processing_fee" => false,
        "liable" => true,
        "amount" => 7870.0,
      ]
];
```

O que eu preciso é tirar a porcentagem de cada um deles em comparação ao total da compra, no caso, o total seria 118,70. Então fiz isso:

```
$eachPercents = [];
$totalAmount = totalAmount($recipients);

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $recipientAmount = cent_to_decimal($recipient['amount']);
    $recipientPercent = round(($recipientAmount * $totalAmount) / 100);

    array_push($eachPercents, $recipientPercent);
}
```

Mas o resultado que isso me gera é inconsistente:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 36.0
  1 => 12.0
  2 => 93.0
]
```

36 + 12 + 93 = 141

A função *totalAmount()* me retorna o total da compra de acordo com o que cada recebedor tem, convertido de centavos para decimal. E o foreach passa cada recebedor, tirando a sua porcentagem relativa a compra e adicionado no conjunto de *eachPercents*, também convertendo de centavos para decimal e fazendo o arredondamento da porcentagem.

Porém, como vcs podem observar, as porcentagens que estão sendo retornadas estão incorretas.

Onde eu estou errado. Agradeço desde já. Abraços!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na fórmula de porcentagem.

```
($recipientAmount * $totalAmount) / 100
```

Deveria ser

```
($recipientAmount * 100) / $totalAmount
```

Isso é o suficiente para resolver o problema. Caso queira saber mais, continue a leitura.

Falando um pouco mais do assunto e apresentando algumas sugestões e observações:

## A fórmula que calcula porcentagem

```
A * 100 / T
```

A -> Valor do qual quer obter a porcentagem em relação a T.

Exemplo:

`30 * 100 / 118.7` resulta em `25.273799494524`

## Um exemplo genérico em PHP:

```
/*
O array original da pergunta não possui essa estrutura, mas fiz assim apenas para simplificar. é algo irrelevante.
*/
$arr = array(
    3000,
    1000,
    7870
);

// Transforma em centavos
$arr = array_map(function($v){return $v / 100;}, $arr);

$total = array_sum($arr);

echo 'total: '.$total.'<br>';

foreach ($arr as $v) {
    echo $v * 100 / $total.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

## Alternativa otimizada

Note que a conversão de centavos é dividir por 100. Mas a expressão matemática fará a multiplicação por 100. Portanto, é um processo redundante, dentro do seu caso específico. Poderia simplificar sem converter os centavos.

Uma nova versão otimizada:

```
$arr = array(
    3000,
    1000,
    7870
);

//Pula essa bagaceira
//$arr = array_map(function($v){return $v / 100;}, $arr);

//Converte apenas o total
$total = array_sum($arr) / 100;

echo 'total: '.$total.'<br>';

foreach ($arr as $v) {
    // Aqui não foi necessário a multiplicação pois seria redundante
    echo $v / $total.'<br>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

## Observação sobre o round()

No código da pergunta está aplicando arredondamento com a função `round()`.
Avalie bem se realmente quer aplicar o arredondamento, pois o resultado será 25, 8 e 66, cuja soma perfaz 99%.

Está comendo 1%. Mantenha a integridade fracionária. A menos que o modelo de negócios queira mesmo "comer" essas pequenas frações. Nesse ponto não posso opinar.

Comment: Perfeito!! Obrigado!